# How to multiply a column in panda frame with a function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data text file with two columns (called X and Y):

```
-2.321404951 0.6231752828E-20
-2.311404951 0.2386233219E-19
-2.301404951 0.8958714819E-19
-2.291404951 0.3297711248E-18
-2.281404951 0.1190194012E-17
-2.271404951 0.4211777921E-17
-2.261404951 0.1461370397E-16
-2.251404951 0.4971725004E-16
-2.241404951 0.1658482566E-15
-2.231404951 0.5424716898E-15
-2.221404951 0.1739847682E-14
-2.211404951 0.5471662415E-14
-2.201404951 0.1687359166E-13
-2.191404951 0.5102494608E-13
-2.181404951 0.1513043201E-12
-2.171404951 0.4399681358E-12
-2.161404951 0.1254584823E-11
-2.151404951 0.3508293965E-11
-2.141404951 0.9620945929E-11
-2.131404951 0.2587465918E-10
-2.121404951 0.6824586233E-10
-2.111404951 0.1765359553E-09
-2.101404951 0.4478742859E-09
```

I would like to obtain data by the formula `f(X)*Y` with `f(X) = 1/(exp(X)-5)`.
Here is my code, but it does not work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys
df = pd.read_csv("dos.txt", sep='delimiter', header=None, engine='python')
F = 1 /  (np.exp((df.loc[:,0] - 5)))
y=df.loc[:,1]*F
print(y)
```

The error is `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>`. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: can you share head of dataframe as `df.head(10).to_dict()`

Comment: There are missing parentheses in your formula.

Comment: oh, it does not have a head. I just add X and Y to explain the function. `{0: {0: '-2.321404951      0.6231752828E-20', 1: '-2.311404951      0.2386233219E-19', 2: '-2.301404951      0.8958714819E-19', 3: '-2.291404951      0.3297711248E-18', 4: '-2.281404951      0.1190194012E-17', 5: '-2.271404951      0.4211777921E-17', 6: '-2.261404951      0.1461370397E-16', 7: '-2.251404951      0.4971725004E-16', 8: '-2.241404951      0.1658482566E-15', 9: '-2.231404951      0.5424716898E-15'}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide a proper separator for parsing the CSV file, so your data was parsed as one string per line instead of multiple numerical columns. Here's a fix:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys
df = pd.read_csv("dos.txt", sep="\s+", header=None, engine='python')
F = 1 /  (np.exp((df.loc[:,0] - 5)))
y=df.loc[:,1]*F
print(y)
```

Comment: This error appears `ParserError: Expected 10 fields in line 54, saw 14` when I change the sep=' '

Comment: @BinhThien Are you working with the exact same data file you posted in your question? That exact file works with the code in my answer. If not, posting the file you're working with (or a different file which also causes the same error) would help us troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: Might need to set `sep="\s+"` so it can deal with multiple spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
def expnFn(x):
    return 1/(np.exp(x)-5)

df['Z'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['X']*expnFn(x['Y']), axis = 1)



 X             Y         Z
0  -2.321405  6.231753e-21  0.580351
1  -2.311405  2.386233e-20  0.577851
2  -2.301405  8.958715e-20  0.575351
3  -2.291405  3.297711e-19  0.572851
4  -2.281405  1.190194e-18  0.570351
5  -2.271405  4.211778e-18  0.567851
6  -2.261405  1.461370e-17  0.565351
7  -2.251405  4.971725e-17  0.562851
8  -2.241405  1.658483e-16  0.560351
9  -2.231405  5.424717e-16  0.557851
10 -2.221405  1.739848e-15  0.555351
11 -2.211405  5.471662e-15  0.552851
12 -2.201405  1.687359e-14  0.550351
13 -2.191405  5.102495e-14  0.547851
14 -2.181405  1.513043e-13  0.545351
15 -2.171405  4.399681e-13  0.542851
16 -2.161405  1.254585e-12  0.540351
17 -2.151405  3.508294e-12  0.537851
18 -2.141405  9.620946e-12  0.535351
19 -2.131405  2.587466e-11  0.532851
20 -2.121405  6.824586e-11  0.530351
21 -2.111405  1.765360e-10  0.527851
22 -2.101405  4.478743e-10  0.525351
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve your float issue, you need to define the dtype when calling read_csv. dtype takes a dict something like:

```
{‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32, ‘c’: ‘Int64’}
```

see: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html.

Then you can just apply a formula to the columns directly, something like:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'y': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]})
df['z'] = (1 / (np.exp(df.x) - 5)) * df.y
```

or if you want to use a function:

```
def fn(x, y):
     return (1 / (np.exp(x) - 5)) * y
df['z'] = fn(df.x, df.y)
```